# How to change contrib.auth.views.password_change view texts in Django?

Tags: python, django

I use Djangos default passoword_change view, but I want to change its text like requirement texts and field labels. For example, I get these texts to the site:

- Your password can't be too similar to your other personal
  information.
- Your password must contain at least 8 characters.

How I can change these texts?

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^password-change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
    {'template_name': 'index/salasanan_vaihto.html'}, name='userauth_password_change'),
url(r'^password-change-done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done',
    {'template_name': 'index/salasanan_vaihto_valmis.html'},
    name='password_change_done'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password is checked using validators [defined by `settings.AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#enabling-password-validation).

Those are classes [implemented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/contrib/auth/password_validation/), so you could write your own and overwrite the `def get_help_text(self)` and/or `validate()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

[These are](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/auth/password_validation.py#L148) a validation errors (see [validation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/)). As such, they are [translated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/) using the standard `gettext` approach. I.e.: in the code, one doesn't hardcode the string itself, but a key (e.g.: `_('my_meg_key')`), and there is an external text catalog (`.po` and `.mo` files), which map these key strings to actual language appropriate full words/sentences. Thus theoretically you could use [Rosetta](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-rosetta) to overwrite these translations yourself.